# How can I make this binary search code more efficient?

Tags: java, search, binary

```
public class MySearch {

    public static int search(MyArray array, int value) {

        int index = -1;

        int start = 0, end = array.length - 1;

        while(start <= end) {

            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            if(array.compToValue(mid, value) == 1) end = mid - 1;
            else if(array.compToValue(mid, value) == -1) start = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }

        return index;

    }
}
```

[image: Error displayed]

In some cases the number of comparisons is exceeded as you can see in the screenshot. I'm not allowed to use read operations (get). The number of comparisons I'm allowed to make is O(logn).

Comment: extract `array.compToValue(mid, value)` into a variable, use this variable in the `if`-clauses instead of calculating the value twice.

Comment: A remark on the code: while possible, we should never skip the curly brackets (`{` and `}`) around a one-line `if`-, `else`-, `for`-. ... body. This can lead to nasty bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it worked! I will take note about the brackets too.

Comment: what's a `MyArray`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code says nothing about whether the array is ordered. If the array is not ordered, you can do only linear search, and a search operation in O(log n) is impossible.

If the array is ordered, as [Turing85's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239222/how-can-i-make-this-binary-search-code-more-efficient#comment124163637_70239222) says:

> extract `array.compToValue(mid, value)` into a variable, use this variable in the `if`-clauses instead of calculating the value twice.

Also useful advice is to always use curly brackets. Java allows to drop it if the code block is only a single line, but doing that is a bad practice.